# SwiftR Invoke method callBack Handler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, swiftr

I am using swiftR in my IOS application, how can handle this error in invoke method and get response from server?

Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

```
hub.invoke("Auth_Code_Request", arguments: [mobile,myMethod!], callback: { (result, error) -> () in

                do {

                    try
                        print(result ?? "this is result")
                }

                catch {

                    print(error)
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's mean invoke method can throw an exception. 
Surround it with a do-catch and use the `try` keyword.

Example:

```
do{
 try myMethod()
} catch {

}
```

Comment: I tried, but this error happens :  Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((Any?, Any?) -> ())?'

Comment: i should call this method : func invoke(_ method: String, arguments: [Any]? = default, callback: ((Any?, Any?) -> ())? = default) throws